# Converting isodate to numerical value

Tags: mongodb, date, timestamp

I am performing tests to ensure I'm getting the dates correctly.

My current tests are: pick a date in mongodb ISODate format and transform it to the numerical value (milliseconds since 1970) and vice versa

Example:

```
var date_test = ISODate ("2013-07-26T22:35:40.373Z")
```

What is the numeric value of this date? Which command is used to get this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply call the [`getTime()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) method, and you get the milliseconds since 1970/01/01

```
> var date_test = ISODate ("2013-07-26T22:35:40.373Z")
> date_test.getTime()
1374878140373
```

to convert milliseconds into date back, construct a new date object:

```
> new Date(1374878140373)
ISODate("2013-07-26T22:35:40.373Z")
```

Comment: I get "19:35:40 GMT-0300 (BRT)" when typing date_test.toTimeString()

Answer (score 5):

Starting `Mongo 4.0`, the [`$toLong`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/) aggregation operator can be applied on a `Date` to get a timestamp:

```
// { mydate: ISODate("2019-06-23T15:52:29.576Z")
db.collection.aggregate({ $project: { timestamp: { $toLong: "$mydate" } } })
// { timestamp: NumberLong("1561305149576") }
```

and vice versa with [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/index.html):

```
// { timestamp: NumberLong("1561305149576") }
db.collection.aggregate({ $project: { mydate: { $toDate: "$timestamp" } } })
// { mydate: ISODate("2019-06-23T15:52:29.576Z") }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having trouble define your model default as new Date() as this will give you long. See sample code below. Then you can always update the long values when you are in Java/Kotlin or any language | This will allow you to skip formatting dates in case you need to.

```
 var UserSchema = new Schema({
username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
code: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
profileUrl: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
firstName: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
lastName: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
coordinates: {
    type: String,
    default: '0.0,0.0'
},
location: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
country: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Tanzania, United Republic of'
},
phoneNumber: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
deviceToken: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
firebaseUserId: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
},
region: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Dar es salaam'
},
role: {
    type: String,
    default: 'normal'
},
lastActiveDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
}
```

});