# Mongodb: Searching using Timestamp ts from Oplog

Tags: mongodb, database-replication

When I try to search through oplog "ts" I'm facing the following issue.

```
db.oplog.rs.find({ts: {$gte: Timestamp(ISODate("2012-12-15T00:00:00Z").getTime(),0)}}).pretty().limit(1)
```

> 2015-12-17T16:42:22.804+0530 E QUERY    Error: The first argument must be in seconds; 1355529600000 is too large (max 2147483647)
>       at (shell):1:30

Why It happens?

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be an issue with the way you are using the Timestamp function.

So value of (ISODate("2012-12-15T00:00:00Z").getTime()) is 1355529600000, which is basically the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01,see [mongodb converting isodate to numerical value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896470/mongodb-converting-isodate-to-numerical-value).

The error occurs when you use this value of 1355529600000 as the first parameter to the Timestamp function which expects the first parameter to be in seconds with a maximum value of 2147483647. You may want to modify the way you are using the Timestamp function based on your requirements.

---

See result of the 2 runs, first with using getTime(), and second of calling Timestamp function :

```
1. 
$ var ts = ISODate("2012-12-15T00:00:00Z").getTime()
$ ts 
1355529600000

2.
$ var ts = Timestamp(ISODate("2012-12-15T00:00:00Z").getTime(),0)
2015-12-17T21:42:43.876+0530 E QUERY    Error: The first argument must be in seconds; 1355529600000 is too large (max 2147483647)
    at (shell):1:10
```